# Django orm to select field that has first three word distinct

Tags: python, django, django-orm, django-aggregation

I want top perform django orm that selects first 3 word of letter as diustinct selection

I have model as below:

```
class Phone(models.Model):
    country = models.ForeignKey(Country, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    name = models.CharField(max_length=2050,null=True,blank=True)
    slug = models.SlugField(max_length=2050,null=True,blank=True)
```

### ** sample values of name are **

---

Xiomi redmi note red ....,
Xiomi redmi note blue ....,
samsung galaxy s10 red ...,
samsung galaxy s10 blue ...,

i want to extract the distinct queryset that has first three word as common

For example:
Xiomi redmi note,
samsung galaxy s10
as a resilt query set

Comment: Which backend? You'll need to create a database-specific [Func](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.2/ref/models/expressions/#func-expressions) expression, annotate on that and then filter on the annotation.

Comment: i am using Postgres as my backend. Database function includes the only character based operations such as LEFT , Substr ,strIndex, there is no function to split words

Comment: You can experiment with `split_part`, `position` and `substring(dbcolumn from regexpattern)`.